# Set up registration FOSUserBundle with FOSRestBundle REST API

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, fosrestbundle, symfony-2.7

***Problem fixed, check my answer.***

I'm building a registration endpoint on my Symfony2.7 rest api.
I am using FosRestBundle and FosUserBundle

**Here is the user model :**

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser {

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;






    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
    }

}
```

\
**Here is the UserType form :** 
\

```
class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('email', 'email')
            ->add('username', null)
            ->add('plainPassword', 'repeated', array(
                'type' => 'password',

                'first_options' => array('label' => 'password'),
                'second_options' => array('label' => 'password_confirmation'),

            ))
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\User',
            'csrf_protection'   => false,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'user';
    }
}
```

**And this the post user controller :**

```
public function postUserAction(\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request) {
        $user = new \AppBundle\Entity\User();
        $form = $this->createForm(new \AppBundle\Form\UserType(), $user);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($user);
            $em->flush();


            $view = $this->view(array('token'=>$this->get("lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_manager")->create($user)), Codes::HTTP_CREATED);

            return $this->handleView($view);

        }

        return array(
            'form' => $form,
        );
    }
```

The problem is that when i submit wrong information, or empty information, the server return a bad formated 500 error with doctrine / mysql details of null value for not null row in state of a json response with the list of bad formated entries.

Any idea on how to fix this behaviour ?
How come the validation get by passed and

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ok after spending a lot of time reading the FOSUserBundle code, and particularly the registration controller and the form factory, i came up with a fully working solution.

Before doing anything don't forget to disable CSRF in your symfony2 configuration.

Here is the controller I use to register :

```
 public function postUserAction(\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request) {


        /** @var $formFactory \FOS\UserBundle\Form\Factory\FactoryInterface */
        $formFactory = $this->get('fos_user.registration.form.factory');
        /** @var $userManager \FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface */
        $userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');
        /** @var $dispatcher \Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface */
        $dispatcher = $this->get('event_dispatcher');

        $user = $userManager->createUser();
        $user->setEnabled(true);

        $event = new \FOS\UserBundle\Event\GetResponseUserEvent($user, $request);
        $dispatcher->dispatch(\FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_INITIALIZE, $event);

        if (null !== $event->getResponse()) {
            return $event->getResponse();
        }

        $form = $formFactory->createForm();
        $form->setData($user);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $event = new \FOS\UserBundle\Event\FormEvent($form, $request);
            $dispatcher->dispatch(\FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS, $event);

            $userManager->updateUser($user);

            if (null === $response = $event->getResponse()) {
                $url = $this->generateUrl('fos_user_registration_confirmed');
                $response = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse($url);
            }

            $dispatcher->dispatch(\FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED, new \FOS\UserBundle\Event\FilterUserResponseEvent($user, $request, $response));

            $view = $this->view(array('token' => $this->get("lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_manager")->create($user)), Codes::HTTP_CREATED);

            return $this->handleView($view);
        }

        $view = $this->view($form, Codes::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
        return $this->handleView($view);
    }
```

Now the tricky part was submiting the form using REST. The problem was that when I sent i JSON like this one :

```
{
        "email":"xxxxx@xxxx.com",
        "username":"xxx",
        "plainPassword":{
            "first":"xxx",
            "second":"xxx"
        }
    }
```

The API was responding like nothing was submited.

The solution is that Symfony2 is waiting for you to encapsulate your form data in the form name !

The question was "I didnt create this form so i dont know what is its name..".
So i went again in the bundle code and found out that the form type was fos_user_registration and the getName function was returning fos_user_registration_form.

As a result i tried to submit my JSON this way :

```
{"fos_user_registration_form":{
        "email":"xxxxxx@xxxxxxx.com",
        "username":"xxxxxx",
        "plainPassword":{
            "first":"xxxxx",
            "second":"xxxxx"
        }
    }}
```

And voila! it worked. 
If you are struggling setting up your fosuserbundle with fosrestbundle and LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle just ask me i'll be glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is this registration without the forms from FOSUserBundle.
Make a POST Request with params: email, user, password.

```
public function postUserAction(Request $request)
{    
    $userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');

    $email = $request->request->get('email');
    $username = $request->request->get('user');
    $password = $request->request->get('password');


    $email_exist = $userManager->findUserByEmail($email);
    $username_exist = $userManager->findUserByUsername($username);

    if($email_exist || $username_exist){
        $response = new JsonResponse();
        $response->setData("Username/Email ".$username."/".$email." existiert bereits");
        return $response;
    }

    $user = $userManager->createUser();
    $user->setUsername($username);
    $user->setEmail($email);
    $user->setLocked(false); 
    $user->setEnabled(true); 
    $user->setPlainPassword($password);
    $userManager->updateUser($user, true);

    $response = new JsonResponse();
    $response->setData("User: ".$user->getUsername()." wurde erstellt");
    return $response;
}
```

Comment: It's not a good idea. Even if you use REST or AJAX, Symfony forms provides a way to handle validations and validation groups and are re-usable. Check my post, works.

Answer (score 0):

[@Adel 'Sean' Helal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1640424/adel-sean-helal) your way doesn't work, at least with last versions of FOSRestBundle, FOSUserBundle and Symfony with Flex. I almost shoot myself in the head trying to make it work. At the end I found the solution and it's pretty simple. Only parse the request is required.

Fragment of my controller code

```
...
$form->setData($user);
// THIS LINE DO THE MAGIC
$data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);

if ($data === null) {
    throw new BadRequestHttpException();
}

$form->submit($data);

if ( ! $form->isValid()) {
    $event = new FormEvent($form, $request);
    $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_FAILURE, $event);
    if (null !== $response = $event->getResponse()) {
        return $response;
    }

    return new JsonResponse($this->getFormErrors($form), Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
}
...
```

The *composer.json* dependencies:

```
...
"symfony/lts": "^3",
"symfony/flex": "^1.0",
"friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "^2.3",
"friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "^2.0",
"lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle": "^2.4",
...
```

My functional test code:

```
namespace App\Tests\Controller;


use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container;

class ApiUserControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    /**
     * @var Container
     */
    private $container;

    public function setUp()
    {
        self::bootKernel();

        $this->container = self::$kernel->getContainer();
    }

    public function testRegistration()
    {
        $userData = [
            'username' => 'test',
            'email' => 'test@email.com',
            'plainPassword' => [
                'first' => 'test123', 'second' => 'test123'
            ]
        ];

        $client = $this->container->get('eight_points_guzzle.client.rest');
        $response = $client->post(
            'api/registration',
            ['json' => $userData]
        );
        $bodyResponse = \GuzzleHttp\json_decode($response->getBody(), true);

        $this->assertEquals(201, $response->getStatusCode());
        $this->assertArrayHasKey('token', $bodyResponse);
        $this->assertNotEmpty($bodyResponse['token']);
    }
}
```

Comment: Good job @rernesto ! Well, I even forgot my post and found it when i saw a notification from you haha. It's quite outdated since it's related de 2.7. 
After many years working with symfony, and still counting, i would really reco you to not use fosuserbundle if it is not mandatory from legacy of your project. Implementing yourself a user model + security provider coupled with LexikJWT is the best choice for a fosrestbundle api :) (did it 2 days ago with SF3 )